# Using Python Linux-only libraries under windows

Tags: libraries, python-3.11

I have found a few Python libraries that I would like to use under windows10 but unfortunately the libraries are targeted for Linux and would need some tweaking like recompiling for using them under windows; examples are e.g. PyPy [exact](https://pypi.org/project/exact/) or [lap](https://github.com/gatagat/lap).

My question is therefore how to make these libraries usable under windows without having to install linux and only minimal change to system settings.

Comment: Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) can be an interesting choice for you, as it's not really installing linux and shouldn't be too complicated to set up. Another option would be to rent a virtual machine from some cloud service provider, but that will cost you money. If you choose the second option, I recommend starting with a $5 low-tier instance, and these are available from a multitude of providers.